# closing jquery confirmation dialog after ajax success

Tags: jquery, ajax

As you can see, I have yes/no confirmation dialog before triggering ajax post.

After success, confirmation dialog remain visible.

What I'm missing?

```
function AbandonOrder() {
    $('<div></div>').appendTo('body')
            .html('<div><strong>Abandon order? <br/> You will be unable to edit this order in the future.</strong></div>')
            .dialog({
                modal: true, title: 'Abandon order', zIndex: 10000, autoOpen: true,
                width: 400, resizable: false,
                buttons: {
                    Yes: function () {
                        jQuery.ajax({
                            url: 'some_URL',
                            type: "POST",
                            dataType: "JSON",
                            success: function (data) {
                                if (data == 'OKAY') {
                                    tosomething();
                                    $('#dlgCard').dialog("close");
                                }
                                else {
                                    $("#divMsg").html("<ul><li>This order cannot be edited.</li></ul>")
                                    $('#dlgMsg').dialog('open');
                                }
                                    //$(this).dialog("close");
                                    $(this).remove();
                            }
                        });
                    },
                    No: function () { $(this).dialog("close"); }
                },
                close: function (event, ui) { $(this).remove(); }
            });
    $('.ui-button-text').css({ fontSize: 12 });
    $('.ui-dialog-title').css({ fontSize: 12 });
}
```

I tryed with

```
 $(this).dialog("close");
```

and

```
 $(this).remove();
```

but confirmation still remain visible.

Comment: have you tried changing the css visibility to hidden?

Comment: @MrCoder I would like to close dialog through jquery. I didn't tried.

Comment: [this site](http://tutorialzine.com/2010/12/better-confirm-box-jquery-css3/) might benefit you. Plus the confimation looks pretty clean too!

Answer (score 0):

It's the scoping of `this` - inside the AJAX request, `this` will be bound to the request object and not your DOM element.  For clarity, I'd rip it out right at the start:

```
var elem = $("<div></div>");
elem.html(...);
```

then at all points you want to close it:

```
elem.dialog("close");
```

You can also pass a `context` option to the AJAX request, which will bind `this` to the object specified:

```
// Assuming we have var elem as above
jQuery.ajax({context: elem[0], success: function() { $(this).dialog('close') }});
```

But this is much less clear than just extracting the variable out at the start.

Answer (score 0):

I  think you should use

```
$( "#dlgMsg" ).dialog( "close" );
```

As you have opened `dlgMsg` dialog But you were trying to close  Card dialog `$('#dlgCard').dialog("close");`